# Count the number of times a Source IP sends packets to Destination IP

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So this is my code:

```
pkt = PcapReader(r'C:\Users\snoopgrapes\Desktop\evidence-packet-analysis.pcap')

srce = []
dstn = []

dict = {}
for p in pkt:
    if IP in p:
        src = p[IP].src
        dst = p[IP].dst
        srce.append(str(src))
        dstn.append(str(dst))
```

I want to count how many times a Source IP sends packets to a destination IP address. I have been able to add the pairs to separate lists. I can merge both lists as well. I have also been able to add the IP pairs to a dictionary. How do I count the number of times the SRC IP sends to a DST IP and store the results in a dictionary?

Example:

```
{50: 192.168.1.10, 10.10.10.50, 35:172.16.10.1,172.16.255.254}
```

Comment: i don't know about  what is in `pkt` which you are looping  but in the loop if you have `src` and `dst` both then you add simply counter for each pair as your example like `{(src1,dst1):counter1,(src2,dst2):counter2}`  so while looping you can simply increase your counter if both are present as it is.

Answer (score 1):

You explicitly asked for a dictionary as the result object -- it might make sense to use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead because you are counting. Even if you need a `dict`, the counter can be simply converted to one. I attached an example at the end of this post.

#### Dictionary

However, to explicitly do this with a dictionary, you could use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with pairs of (`source`, `destination`) as key and just increment the stored number for every pair:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

# ...

counts = defaultdict(int)
for packet in packets:
    if IP in packet:
        source = packet[IP].src
        destination = packet[IP].dst
        counts[(source, destination)] += 1
```

minimal working example:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

class ObjectDict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        if key in self:
            return self[key]

IP = "IP"

packets = [
{
   "IP": ObjectDict({
      "src": "192.168.1.1",
      "dst": "192.168.1.1",
   }),
},
{
   "IP": ObjectDict({
      "src": "192.168.1.1",
      "dst": "192.168.1.1",
   }),
},
{
   "IP": ObjectDict({
      "src": "192.168.1.2",
      "dst": "192.168.1.1",
   }),
},
{
   "IP": ObjectDict({
      "src": "192.168.1.1",
      "dst": "192.168.1.2",
   }),
},
]

counts = defaultdict(int)
for packet in packets:
    if IP in packet:
        source = packet[IP].src
        destination = packet[IP].dst
        counts[(source, destination)] += 1

print(dict(counts))
```

output:

```
{('192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.1'): 2, ('192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.1'): 1, ('192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2'): 1}
```

If using `defaultdict` is not an option, you would simply replace the addition line with:

```py
counts[(source, destination)] = counts.get((source, destination), 0) + 1
```

utilizing the default value that can be used with [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)

#### Counter

To use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), you could do

```py
# assume same setup as above

counter_generator = ((p[IP].src, p[IP].dst) for p in packets if IP in p)
counts = Counter(counter_generator)

print(counts)
print()
print(dict(counts))
```

with output:

```
Counter({('192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.1'): 2, ('192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.1'): 1, ('192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2'): 1})

{('192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.1'): 2, ('192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.1'): 1, ('192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2'): 1}
```